# Python selecting products that meet certain conditions using triples

Tags: python, python-3.x

the condition triple is set in a way that (i,c,v) where i is the integer feature of index, c is a relation symbol, and v is some feature of value,
for example 
for a give list of fruits
using feature 'name','color','weight','price'

```
fruits =[['Apple','Red',1,20],
         ['orange','orange',2,10],
         ['pear','green',3,25],
cheap = (3,'<=',10)
```

i need to implement a function called selection(products, conditions)
where selection(fruits,cheap) will return
`['orange','orange',2,10]`
and this function should work for any given products and any given amount of conditions as long as it holds the format of 'name','color','weight','price' for products and for condition it holds the format of (i,c,v),i have no idea how to start without hard coding it and it should be implemented without hard coding, what i have so far

```
    x = len(conditions)
    z = x - 1
    i = 0
    while i != x:
        if conditions[i + 1] == '<':
            if products[conditions[i]] < conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)
        elif conditions[i + 1] == '<=':
            if products[conditions[i]] <= conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)

        elif conditions[i + 1] == '==':
            if products[conditions[i]] == conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)
        elif conditions[i + 1] == '>=':
            if products[conditions[i]] >= conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)
        elif conditions[i + 1] == '>':
            if products[conditions[i]] > conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)
        elif conditions[i + 1] == '!=':
            if products[conditions[i]] != conditions[i + 2]:
                n = True
                checker.append(n)
            else:
                n = False
                checker.append(n)
        i = i + 3
    if 'False' in checker:
        pass
    else:
        return products
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be by using `eval()`.
I know many do not like to use `eval()` for security reasons, but in this case, I don't see why not.

Also, I would use pandas to deal with that kind of data-structure.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: fruits =[['Apple','Red',1,20],
   ...:          ['orange','orange',2,10],
   ...:          ['pear','green',3,25]]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns=['name', 'color', 'x', 'y'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
     name   color  x   y
0   Apple     Red  1  20
1  orange  orange  2  10
2    pear   green  3  25
```

Now the let's make a function ad hoc using eval.

```
 In [5]: def f(df, x, op, y):
    ...:     return eval(f'df.loc[(df.x {op} {x}) & (df.y {op} {y})]')
    ...:
    ...:

In [6]: f(df, 3, '<=', 10)
Out[6]:
     name   color  x   y
1  orange  orange  2  10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to let Python do the work for you or you could use a dictionary to map to lambda functions for the various condition operators:

## Using eval():

```
def selection1(products,triple):
    i,c,v = triple
    condition = eval(f"lambda p: p[{i}] {c} v",{"v":v})
    return next(filter(condition,products),None)
```

## Using a dictionary:

```
def selection2(products,triple):
    i,c,v      = triple
    conditions = { "<" : lambda p:p[i] <  v,
                   "<=": lambda p:p[i] <= v,
                   "==": lambda p:p[i] == v,
                   "!=": lambda p:p[i] != v,
                   ">=": lambda p:p[i] >= v,
                   ">" : lambda p:p[i] >= v
                 }
    return next(filter(conditions[c],products),None)
```